# How can you make sure you have your fee recipient set correctly?

Tags: etherscan, proof-of-stake, consensus, the-merge

Using [Teku](https://github.com/ConsenSys/teku), [Prysm](https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/getting-started), or other consensus client, how can you make sure your fee recipient is getting the fees from staking?

Is there a way to see where your fees are going on the block explorers? Should we see fees coming into the recipient address quite often?